# Proper memory management when invoking a delegate callback that may cause object to be released

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, delegates

I'm trying to figure out the best practice for memory management around invoking a delegate callback.
One issue I had seen in the past is that invoking a delegate callback may cause the object to be deallocated before returning, which may cause it to crash if the object tries to access its own properties after invoking the callback.

For example, an object (e.g. `A`) may do something like this:

```
- (void)doStuff
{
    [_delegate done];
    NSLog(@"msg = %@", _msg);
}
```

If invoking `done` leads to `A` getting deallocated, the subsequent attempt to access `_msg` will result in a BAD_ACCESS crash.

It is possible to get around this by, say, delaying the invocation of `done` till the next run loop (e.g. by doing a `dispatch_async`), but that would force us to have to make it asynchronous. Alternatively, we can retain `self` prior to calling `done` and releasing right after, but that just seems like a hacky workaround as well. Does any one have a recommended style for dealing with this issue?

Comment: Are you using ARC?  If not then perhaps additional `retain`/`release` around the delegate invocation would avoid the deallocation of the object.

Comment: If 'A' is telling the delegate it's done, why does it want to do something else after that? If it's truly done it should really expect to be released...

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above, retaining `self` before invoking the delegate would indeed let us work around this issue.  
  
I guess I am more interested in knowing whether that is the right practice - whether the contract of the delegate pattern is that the sender should be responsible for its own life cycle to make sure it doesn't get deallocated while invoking the delegate callback; or if the delegate/owner should be the one responsible for making sure the sender doesn't get deallocated (by autoreleasing instead of releasing or perhaps by delaying the release).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this question really has anything to do with 'delegates' to be honest but more just memory management in general.

If you're not finished with an object make sure you are still 'retaining' it. When you're finished with it 'release' it and don't access it any further.

Also try and move to ARC if possible and life becomes much easier! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because the delegate you want to call refers to a deallocated object.To fix this crash you need to set `Delegate = nil;` in your dealloc method.
You can not set property of delegate as `retain` as it will cause issue in memory management.

Answer (score -2):

It shouldn't be possible, that the delegate method releases the sender. What let you run in this situation?

It is always possible to pair +1 with -1 methods in one (C) block.

If you work with MRC:
Anyway, I would prefer a retain + autorelease on sender in the delegate method before causing the deallocation over a retain + release in the delegate. Therefore the sender should be added as a parameter to the delegate method as usual:

```
- (void)senderIsDone:(Sender*)sender
{
   [[sender retain] autorelease];
…
   [sender release]; // Something like this in your code
}
```

But at all: This should not happen.

Another strategy is to delay that code that causes the deallocation. In the example above

```
- (void)senderIsDone:(Sender*)sender
{
    [sender performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector( release ) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; // Whatever make the sender disappear
}
```

Comment: One retain and 2 releases?

Comment: 1 release is already there and the problem. The paired creation/retain/whatever+1 is obviously outside his delegate method. This is the reason for the statement:

"It shouldn't be possible, that the delegate method releases the sender. What let you run in this situation?"

And as I said, the best solution is to get ride of that deallocation.

Comment: If the delegate is the owner of the sender then it has the right to release the sender. That the sender is released does not require a mismatch in retain / release pairs. You perform selector answer is better.

Comment: The mismatch is already there! From his question:
"One issue I had seen in the past is that invoking a delegate callback may cause the object to be dealloc'd before returning,"
There is already a overrelease in -done otherwise the sender wouldn't be dealloc'd! I did not add it. I added a retain-autorelease-pair.
The performSelector… solution is no better, because there is still a overrelease. It is simply delayed, but stays there. 
The best solution is to get ride of his overrelease, if possible. If this is not possible, you can add a retain-autorelease (=pair) to his already existing release.

Comment: It isn't necessarily an over release. It can simply be the owner not needing the sender any more. This is perfectly legal. If the sender tells the owner that it is finished it should expect to be released, it shouldn't expect to be able to do more work afterwards. The perform selector gives it a chance to do a bit more work (not that it should try).

Comment: If it is not an overrelease, there is no release added by *him* in his method. And then there are not 1 retain and 2 releases, but 1 retain and 1 (auto)release. As you can see in the comment "// Something like this in -->your<-- code". I did *not* add the second release.
Again, but actually I do not know, how to explain it deeper: I added *1* retain and *1* (auto)release. This is definetly a pair.
If something else causes the dealloc'd, it is still a *pair* to add [[sender retain] autorelease] at the beginning.

Comment: You would be better omitting the release you think might exist and do the retain + autorelease in the sender as this encapsulates the knowledge that the sender wants to do some more work after it should be complete.

Comment: I said *several times*, that it is better to omit the release. Shall I quote it again?

Comment: There is no knowledge, that the sender wants to do something after return. The sender sends a message and after executing the method, the called method *always* return to the sender's method. It is *always* illegal to continue the sender's method with self on a dealloc'd object. The delegate knows that. It will return to the sender. Therefore the problem must be solved in the delegate, because the sender's method behaves as every other method written in Objective-C in the last 30 years.